# Correlation coefficient of explanatory variables in D-optimal design

Tags: machine-learning, experiment-design

In the D-optimal design of design of experiments, some books make the following claims.

> The absolute value of the correlation coefficient becomes smaller

I understand that the covariance is minimized when there are two explanatory variables, that is, when the variance-covariance matrix is a 2 × 2 matrix.

On the other hand, is it obvious that "the absolute value of the correlation coefficient is minimized" when the explanatory variables are 3 or more?

Or is it possible to prove it mathematically?

Comment: From which book? Can you give more context, maybe a more complete quote?

Answer (score 1):

Let us look at the problem of finding a D-optimal design for a linear regression problem with two predictors, so the model has the form
$$ Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{i1} +\beta_2 x_{i2} + \epsilon_i $$ where $i=1,2,\dotsc,n$,  and we have the usual assumptions of independence  and constant variance for the disturbance terms $\epsilon_i$.  Writing in  matrix form
$$ Y=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x_{11} & x_{12} \\
                     1 & x_{21} & x_{22} \\
                      \ddots \\
                     1 & x_{n1} & x_{n2} \end{pmatrix} \beta + \epsilon $$ or more compactly $Y=X \beta +\epsilon$. Also write the three column vectors building the matrix $X$ as $1, x_1, x_2$.

Let us assume that $(x_{i1}, x_{i2})^T \in [-1,1]\times [-1,1]$, so the design space is a Cartesian product. This is not necessary, but is an often seen case. D-optimality consists in maximizing the determinant of $X^T X$. Write this out as
$$ X^T X = \begin{pmatrix} 
n      & 1^T x_1 & 1^T x_2 \\
1^T x_1& x_1^T x_1& x_1^T x_2\\ 
1^T x_2& x_1^T x_2& x_2^T x_2\\ \end{pmatrix}
$$
**Simple case where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are centered**
Then $X^T X$ simplifies to
$$ X^T X = \begin{pmatrix} 
n      & 0 & 0 \\
0 & x_1^T x_1& x_1^T x_2\\ 
0 & x_1^T x_2& x_2^T x_2\\ \end{pmatrix}
$$   Calculate its determinant by expanding along the first row:
$$ \vert X^T X \vert = n \cdot \left(x_1^T x_1 \cdot x_2^T x_2 - (x_1^T x_2)^2 \right) $$
It is clear that this is maximized by choosing $x_1$ and $x_2$ as orthogonal, and then maximizing the norm of each of them. The last is achieved by letting half of them bee equal to $+1$, the other half $-1$. Which is possible if $n$ is even. In this case, this explains why a D-optimal design tends to choose uncorrelated predictors, if the restrictions of the design permits that, or falting that, tends to minimize the correlation.
**The general case**
We will not try a direct attack on the determinant, but will utilize the [Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_inequality) or even more directly, its sibling the less known [Fischer's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fischer%27s_inequality). Let us state the last (see the Wikipedia link for proofs).  Fisher's inequality gives an upper bound for the determinant of a positive semidefinite matrix in terms of the determinants of its principal diagonal blocks. Let
$$ M = \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ B^T & C \end{pmatrix}
$$ then
$$ \vert M \vert \le \vert A\vert \cdot \vert C \vert $$
and if $M$ is positive definite then equality is achieved if and only if all the entries of $B$ are zero.

Apply this to our matrix $X^T X$, and identify the blocks as $A=n$ and so on. Again we see that to achieve the upper bound, we need the predictors centered, with correlation zero, and the norms of $x_1$ and $x_2$ maximized. Sometimes restrictions on our design problem will not permit this, but then any optimization algorithm will try to find a solution  approximating this ideal case, which explains the terminology *tends to find solutions minimizing the correlation between the predictors*.

To go deeper into this, the following paper might be useful: [More subtle versions of the Hadamard inequality](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0024379517304135?token=65B1EC29B86A916052F2C1152527393E0E71929E241F06E3B919E4F21C822F1D93EA2CEB3244FC8DD3BEC306001E818A&originRegion=us-east-1&originCreation=20220415041553) by Michał Różański, Roman Wituła  and Edyta Hetmaniok.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I clearly understand the general case by your answers.
Also, I would like to read the papers presented and deepen my understanding.